# When Process Exited Delete File Visual Basic

Tags: .net, process

So I have a program which gets images offline and then displays the image in a PictureBox. When the user clicks on the image in the PictureBox, the program downloads the image into temporary files and then opens the picture using the default photo viewer. But when the user exits the picture I want to delete this image from my temporary files, but I'm having a few issues doing this.

So here is my code at the moment:

```
Public Event Exited As EventHandler
Public WithEvents p As New Process

Public Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(picture, "C:\Windows\Temp" + "\" + uname + ".png")
    AddHandler p.Exited, AddressOf Me.p_Exited
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Windows\Temp" + "\" + uname + ".png"
    p.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    p.Start()
End Sub


Public Sub p_Exited(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles p.Exited
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Windows\Temp" + "\" + uname + ".png")
End Sub
```

So I'm getting the issue when the process is started, all of the code works with no errors it's just when I close the picture/exiting the process. The bottom sub doesn't pick up on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
    Private Sub RunningOrNot()

       Dim p() As Process
       p = Process.GetProcessesByName("nameofyourprocess")

       If p.Count > 0 Then
          'running
       Else
          'not running
       End If

    End Sub
```

edit: `.Count` is not allowed in VS2010. So if you need, use `.Length` instead.